# Elasticsearch filter results by field

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I'm new to dsl and this seems simple. The code should count total entries by the hour, within the date range specified. I added a `bool` such that the results should have a field called 'message' which should contain '[success'

```
GET sample_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "[sucess"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2021-01-01",
        "lte": "2021-01-10"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "hit_count_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "hour"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error returned is

```
  {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line" : 13,
        "col" : 5
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line" : 13,
    "col" : 5
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `range` query also in the `must` clause. Modify your query as shown below

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "[sucess"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2021-01-01",
              "lte": "2021-01-10"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "hit_count_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "hour"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @HC LW please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, someone else replied elsewhere with similar code like yours that runs, but both returns 0 hits. 

I feel like it's my fault describing the issue wrong, but it seems very simple. literally all I do, in the Discover visualization of the index, is specify a date range, and type in the search bar "[success" which is contained in a string field called 'message', then 2 hits are shown. @ESCoder

Comment: It seems like just using the string matching doesn't work on its own: `{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "[success"
          }
        } 
      ]
    }
  } 
}`

Comment: @HCLW can you please share your index mapping and a sample index data on which you are performing your query. This will help me to provide you a more better solution to your problem

Comment: @HCLW please don't ask a separate question (related to the same issue). IMHO its better to add any modification to the same question here, rather than asking a separate question each time -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765129/aggregation-with-range-and-match-phrase

Comment: unintuitive as it is, the answer to this question is likely somewhere in my history of asked questions which :( i'm too lazy to sift through but if anyone else has this problem, it's there somewhere.