# Aggregation with range and match_phrase

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I want to count the total failed logins each day (between 2021-07-18 and 2021-07-26).

The query here will return only hits for failed logins between those dates. If I removed the 'match_phrase' component that looks for failed logins, it will count just the total logins each day. But including the 'match_phrase' part will only return the 'failed login' documents, and not count how many failed per day.

**Aggregation Query**

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 8,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {"match_phrase": {
            "message": "[Failed login"
            }
          },
          {"range": {
            "@timestamp":{
              "gte":"2021-07-18",
              "lte":"2021-07-26"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "hit_count_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I think I think I need to add something to the 'aggs' section? or is using 'match_phrase' fundamentally not correctly applied for aggregation purposes? **Mapping for 'message'**...

```
"message" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : "whitespace"
        }
```

**Sample 'failed login' Document** from hits, trimmed for brevity...

```
{
        "_index" : "log-c0001_log-004444",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "DAwerFPXIHfH_4rWX",
        "_score" : 29.337955,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "<14>1 2021-07-22T07:56:01.598708+00:00 - -  Event [247458] [1-1] [2021-07-22T07:56:01.598364Z] [info] [] [247458] [Failed login]",
          "@timestamp" : "2021-07-22T07:56:01.596Z"
        }
```

**Response**:

```
        {
      "took" : 886,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 162,
        "successful" : 162,
        "skipped" : 144,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 3,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 29.337955,
        "hits" : [
            {..},
            {..},
            {..}
 ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "hit_count_per_day" : {
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please add a document and response that you get?

Comment: What's up Saeed. Added the response for aggregation and an edited sample document. Hopefully this is what you need. @SaeedNasehi

Comment: You have missed @ in the name of field you added in aggregations. change timestamp to @timestamp in aggs field.

Comment: oh nice. Thanks a lot. you basically write this whole thing for me lol @SaeedNasehi

Comment: You're welcome, buddy!